# How to run this in sudo?

Tags: command-line, sudo, quoting, suse

I have this line that I execute from php

`sudo -u db2inst1 -s -- "/opt/ibm/db2/current/bin/db2 connect to PLC; /opt/ibm/db2/current/bin/db2 \"update EDU.contact set MOBILE_PHONE = '123'\""`

it works fine on Sudo version **1.7.2**.

Now I got new server with `SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)`. There was no sudo so I installed it from repository (Sudo version **1.6.9p17**) But know the above syntax doesn't work. It throws `bin/bash: /opt/ibm/db2/current/bin/db2 connect to PLC; /opt/ibm/db2/current/bin/db2 "update EDU.contact set MOBILE_PHONE = '123'": No such file or directory`

Any idea how I can make this work?

If I run `/opt/ibm/db2/current/bin/db2 connect to PLC; /opt/ibm/db2/current/bin/db2 "update EDU.contact set MOBILE_PHONE = '123'"` under db2inst1 account everythings work just fine.

Comment: Would be nice to say why the down vote...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm really not quite sure why you're getting this error. I have a system with sudo 1.8.3 on it, and the documentation clearly says something like `sudo -s "echo hi"` should work, but it doesn't.

The way I've always done this is to do the same thing `-s [command]` does, but manually.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo hi'
```

or in your case

```
sudo -u db2inst1 sh -c "/opt/ibm/db2/current/bin/db2 connect to PLC; /opt/ibm/db2/current/bin/db2 \"update EDU.contact set MOBILE_PHONE = '123'\""
```

It's more compatible, as the `-s` argument hasn't always been around (and I unfortunately have some really old machines at work).

Edit:
What's happening in the error you're getting is that it's looking for an executable which is literally named `db2 "update EDU.contact set MOBILE_PHONE = '123'"` in a directory called `/opt/ibm/db2/current/bin/db2 connect to PLC; /opt/ibm/db2/current/bin` (yes, it looks for `db2 connect to PLC;` as a directory). This obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: I really don't understand your explanation :-) better say I don't understand how this could happen. But your solution works nicely. Thank you.